# Error while creating the second element of a list after the head has been deleted an recreated

Tags: c, list

As the title declares, I have a problem concerning an ordered list; 
the line where the program crashes is signed in the code below; anyone have idea of where I'm wrong?
Here the job.h header:

```
typedef struct
{
    char stringa[DIM];
    unsigned int priority;
} Job;
```

Here the link declaration (I know it's weird, but my professor want this):

```
typedef struct QUEUEnode *link;
```

And here the incriminated module:

```
#include "ordinate_list.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct QUEUEnode
{
    link next;
    Job job;
};

void QUEUEinit(Job);
void QUEUEput_ordered(Job a);
void QUEUEfind_link(link b, Job a);
void QUEUElink(link upper, link bottom, Job a);
void print_list_(link, int);

link head=NULL;
int QUEUED_nodes=0;

void add_QUEUEnode(Job a)
{
    if(QUEUED_nodes==0)
    {
        printf("Coda iniziallizata...\n\n");
        QUEUEinit(a);
    }
    else
    {
        QUEUEput_ordered(a);
    }
}

void QUEUEinit(Job a) //OK
{
    head = malloc(sizeof(struct QUEUEnode));
    head->next=NULL;
    head->job=a;
    QUEUED_nodes++;
}

void QUEUEput_ordered(Job a)
{
    if(head->job.priority<=a.priority)
    {
        QUEUElink(NULL, head, a);
    }
    else
    {
        QUEUEfind_link(head, a);
    }
}

void QUEUEfind_link(link b, Job a)
{
    if(b->next==NULL)
    {
        QUEUElink(b, NULL, a);

    }
    else if((b->job.priority > a.priority) && (b->next->job.priority < a.priority))
    {
        QUEUElink(b, b->next, a);

    }
    else QUEUEfind_link(b->next, a);
    return;
}

void QUEUElink(link upper, link bottom, Job a)
{
    link tmp;
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct QUEUEnode));
    tmp->job=a;

    if(upper==NULL)
    {
        tmp->next=head;
        head=tmp;
    }
    else if(bottom==NULL)
    {
        bottom->next=tmp;
        tmp->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        upper->next=tmp; //HERE! DAMN BUG
        tmp->next=bottom;
    }
    QUEUED_nodes++;
}

Job QUEUEget_top()
{
    Job a;
    link tmp=head;
    a=head->job;
    head=head->next;
    free(tmp);
    QUEUED_nodes--;
    return a;
}
```

As you can see from the code, the program crashes at an unusual line. The only thing I haven't tried is to change the priority of the jobs, putting the second before the head and not after; Do it worth the try?

Comment: One problem, if bottom == NULL then you should not do bottom->next = tmp;

Comment: Another thing, check to see that malloc does not return NULL.

Comment: Finally, your code would simplify and be more robust if you'd just pass in only the node after (or before, your choice) which the new node should be inserted to QUEUElink().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you haven't provided ordinate_list.h, and your posted code doesn't have a main(), so we can't possibly tell you for certain what the problem is. I can, however, tell you for certain what *a* problem is... in your `QUEUElink()` function, you have a guaranteed failure right here:

```
else if(bottom==NULL)
{
    bottom->next=tmp;
    tmp->next=NULL;
}
```

If `bottom` is equal to `NULL`, I can assure your with absolute, utter certainty that `bottom->next=tmp;` is impossible, and will segfault.

Comment: oh you're right, i didn't posted the main because the main is just few lines which call functions from another module which call those functions! :P

By the way thank you  :) i corrected `bottom` with `upper` which is the element before the one that have to be linked :)

Comment: Yes :) [here](http://sdrv.ms/13nmEDv) it is if you want to check the other modules!

Comment: good. Can't take you up on your kind offer to check the other modules because of the capricious firewall/filtering web proxy I sit behind.